# Бесконечный скролл постов с подменой URL, title, description

Tags: php, laravel, прокрутка

Как при прокрутке поста, подгрузить следующий (бесконечная лента), при этом, чтобы в обе стороны при скролле менялись `title`, `URL`?

Есть ли инструкции или готовые пакеты для реализации? Используется `PHP`, `Laravel`.

Для демонстрации работы того что нужно, можно взять сайт: https://iz.ru/1101264/2020-12-17/cas-zapretil-rossiiskii-sportsmenam-vystupat-pod-flagom-strany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил свою же проблему таким образом.

Выбираем все нужные статьи. Первой идёт нужная нам по запросу.

```
public function index($id)
{
    $articles = Article::query()
        ->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, $id) DESC") // первой идёт статья по запросу
        ->paginate(1);

    return view('article')->with('articles', $articles);
}
```

Формируем шаблон со статьёй. Сам бесконечный скролл работает на [Jquery Jscroll](https://jscroll.com). Делается очень легко! Подключается сам скрипт и простейшая конфигурация.

Шаблон статьи выглядит примерно так:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
<div class="jscroll">

    {{-- данные для подмены url, title и т.д. --}}
    <div data-marker class="g-hidden"
         data-id="{{ $article->id }}"
         data-title="{{ $article->title }}"
         data-description="{{ $article->description }}"
         data-url="{{ route('article', $article->id) }}">
    </div>

    {{-- заг, подзаг, фотки, текст... --}}

</div>

{{-- пагинация --}}
<div class="d-none">
    {{ $articles->links('pagination-infinite') }}
</div>

</div>
@endforeach
```

Данные для подстановки скрыты методом абсолютного позиционирования. Если блок скрыть полностью, то не будет отслеживаться позиция при скролле.

```
.g-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -9999px;
}
```

Шаблон для пагинации выглядит стандартно и максимально урезанно (только кнопка "далее").

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav class="pagination justify-content-center b-pagination">
        <ul class="pagination">
            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">
                        Вперед
                    </a>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </nav>
@endif
```

Подключение Jscroll:

```
$('.jscroll').jscroll({
    padding: 400,
    nextSelector: '.page-link[rel="next"]',
    contentSelector: 'div.jscroll',
});
```

Сам основной скрипт:

```
// переборка маркеров <div data-marker> для определения позиции где мы находимся и подмены нужных данных
function checkMarkers() {
    const markers = $('.b-wrap__content [data-marker]').get().reverse(); // в обратном порядке для перебора
    if (markers.length < 1) {
        return; // данные для подмены не найдены
    }

    // перебираем маркеры и проверяем расстояние до шапки сайта +300 px
    for (let element of markers) {
        let toTop = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        // метка близка к шапке, меняем параметры страницы
        if (toTop < 300) {
            changePageAttributes(element.dataset);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function changePageAttributes(data) {
    // сверяем url маркера с текущим url страницы
    const url = $(location).attr("href"); 
    if (url === data.url) {
        return true; // находимся на той же статье, менять параметры не требуется
    }

    window.history.replaceState(data.url, data.title, data.url); // подменяем url
    document.title = data.title; // подменяем title
    $("meta[name='description']").attr('content', data.description); // подменяем description
}
```

Основная задача выполнена! С JS на Вы, поэтому делал как мог!

Answer (score 8):

Вас минусят за то, что в вашем вопросе нет примеров кода, что сильно противоречит первопричине создания данного сайта, для остальных пользователей это выглядит как "Напишите за меня код, я не хочу думать и терять время и поисковиков для меня не существует".

**Из того что поможет решить вашу задачу:**

https://snipp.ru/php/loading-scrolling

https://webformyself.com/beskonechnyj-skroll-s-avtomaticheskoj-zagruzkoj-kontenta/

Из приведенных примеров вы можете взять код и адаптировать под свою задачу, попутно добавив необходимое и если у вас не получится, можете повторно разместить задание с кодом и вам помогут его доработать.

Comment: @MixJay  пожалуйста. Надеюсь помог навести вас на нужные образцы кода. Ищется на самом деле легко "Бесконечная страница прокрутки PHP Mysql" и все.  В целом очень сильно рекомендую начать изучать английский, там материалов гораздо больше ценных от первоисточников ну или на крайний случай пользоваться встроенными переводчиками в браузерах.

Comment: По ссылкам можно посмотреть лишь вариант реализации самого скролла, но без смены параметров страницы. Для простейшей реализации достаточно функционала библиотек Jscroll или Infinite Ajax Scroll. Сама бесконечная подгрузка трудностей не вызывает (об этом писал в шапке при создании конкурса). А вот чтобы по скроллу в обоих направлениях менялись title & URL - сложновато.

Comment: @MixJay   title - должен быть идентичен названию записи поста? URL - это ссылка на этот пост? Все верно?

Comment: Да, вы всё верно понимаете! Помимо этого еще и description, OG-теги... Такой подход даст глубину просмотров, позволить добавлять материалы в избранное с правильными заголовками и ссылками, а так же делиться ими. Счетчики посещаемости смогут регистрировать подгруженные страницы. Мысленно представляю, что можно передать данные в формате json и подставить во вьюху, оттуда данные забрать скриптом и подставлять при скролле. Еще одна вытекающая проблема - когда и как считать страницу прокрученной (когда влез заголовок h1 или основная часть контента...)

Comment: @MixJay  Вы уж определитесь по порядку, с чего начать. И тогда уже приступим. Основной код прокрутки удалось собрать вам?